# Trying to use Dice Loss with UNET

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science

I'm trying to implement the UNET at the keras website:

[Image segmentation with a U-Net-like architecture](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/)

With only one change. use Dice loss instead of "sparse_categorical_crossentropy". However, every time I try something, I get different error. I'm coding on google colab using Tensorflow 2.7.

For example, I tried using

```
def DiceLoss(targets, inputs, smooth=1e-6):
    
    #flatten label and prediction tensors
    
    inputs = K.flatten(inputs)
    targets = K.flatten(targets)
    
    intersection = K.sum(K.dot(targets, inputs))
    
    dice = (2*intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(targets) + K.sum(inputs) + smooth)
    
    return 1 - dice
```

The eror I got:

***ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for '{{node DiceLoss99/MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false](DiceLoss99/Reshape_1, DiceLoss99/Reshape)' with input shapes: [?], [?].***

The problem is on this line:

```
intersection = K.sum(K.dot(targets, inputs))
```

I also tried this library:

```
 !pip install git+https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models
 # define optomizer
 n_classes=3
 LR = 0.0001
 optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)
 dice_loss_sm = sm.losses.DiceLoss(class_weights=K.ones_like(n_classes))
```

However, I got the following error:

***TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.***

the remaining code is same as in keras.io. but I listed below for completeness :

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def get_model(img_size, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=img_size + (3,))

    ### [First half of the network: downsampling inputs] ###

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    # Blocks 1, 2, 3 are identical apart from the feature depth.
    for filters in [64, 128, 256]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    ### [Second half of the network: upsampling inputs] ###

    for filters in [256, 128, 64, 32]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(previous_block_activation)
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, padding="same")(residual)
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    # Add a per-pixel classification layer
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model


# Free up RAM in case the model definition cells were run multiple times
keras.backend.clear_session()

# Build model
model = get_model(img_size, num_classes)
model.summary()
# Configure the model for training.
# We use the "sparse" version of categorical_crossentropy
# because our target data is integers.

#   notice I changed the lose the dice loss instead of sparse_categorical_crossentropy
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("oxford_segmentation.h5", save_best_only=True)
]

# Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch.
epochs = 15
model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks)
```

***EDIT***

This detailed error message when trying the lose library at [segmentation_models](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models):
[image]

The issue on this code :

```
    backend = kwargs['backend']
     Args:
        gt: ground truth 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
        pr: prediction 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
        class_weights: 1. or list of class weights, len(weights) = C
        class_indexes: Optional integer or list of integers, classes to consider, if ``None`` all classes are used.
        beta: f-score coefficient
        smooth: value to avoid division by zero
        per_image: if ``True``, metric is calculated as mean over images in batch (B),
            else over whole batch
        threshold: value to round predictions (use ``>`` comparison), if ``None`` prediction will not be round
    Returns:
        F-score in range [0, 1]
  

  """
Args:
        gt: ground truth 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
        pr: prediction 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
        class_weights: 1. or list of class weights, len(weights) = C
        class_indexes: Optional integer or list of integers, classes to consider, if ``None`` all classes are used.
        beta: f-score coefficient
        smooth: value to avoid division by zero
        per_image: if ``True``, metric is calculated as mean over images in batch (B),
            else over whole batch
        threshold: value to round predictions (use ``>`` comparison), if ``None`` prediction will not be round
    Returns:
        F-score in range [0, 1]
    """
Args:
        gt: ground truth 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
        pr: prediction 4D keras tensor (B, H, W, C) or (B, C, H, W)
        class_weights: 1. or list of class weights, len(weights) = C
        class_indexes: Optional integer or list of integers, classes to consider, if ``None`` all classes are used.
        beta: f-score coefficient
        smooth: value to avoid division by zero
        per_image: if ``True``, metric is calculated as mean over images in batch (B),
            else over whole batch
        threshold: value to round predictions (use ``>`` comparison), if ``None`` prediction will not be round
    Returns:
        F-score in range [0, 1]
    """

        gt, pr = gather_channels(gt, pr, indexes=class_indexes, **kwargs)
        pr = round_if_needed(pr, threshold, **kwargs)
        axes = get_reduce_axes(per_image, **kwargs)
    
        # calculate score
        tp = backend.sum(gt * pr, axis=axes) # the issue here 
        fp = backend.sum(pr, axis=axes) - tp
        fn = backend.sum(gt, axis=axes) - tp
    
        score = ((1 + beta ** 2) * tp + smooth) \
                / ((1 + beta ** 2) * tp + beta ** 2 * fn + fp + smooth)
        score = average(score, per_image, class_weights, **kwargs)
    
        return score
```

The code for gt,pr and axis is here:

```
def get_reduce_axes(per_image, **kwargs):
    backend = kwargs['backend']
    axes = [1, 2] if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else [2, 3]
    if not per_image:
        axes.insert(0, 0)
    return axes


def gather_channels(*xs, indexes=None, **kwargs):
    """Slice tensors along channels axis by given indexes"""
    if indexes is None:
        return xs
    elif isinstance(indexes, (int)):
        indexes = [indexes]
    xs = [_gather_channels(x, indexes=indexes, **kwargs) for x in xs]
    return xs


def round_if_needed(x, threshold, **kwargs):
    backend = kwargs['backend']
    if threshold is not None:
        x = backend.greater(x, threshold)
        x = backend.cast(x, backend.floatx())
    return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 1-dimensional vectors to `K.dot`, while the ValueError is saying that `K.dot` requires arrays with 2-dimensions.

You can replace it with element-wise multiplication, i.e. `intersection = K.sum(targets *inputs)`

Comment: Thanks ... what about the 2nd  error: TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.

Comment: Can't tell which line is raising the error without seeing the stacktrace. However, the error is saying that one of the multiplication operations is mixing ints and floats. You'll need to check the data types of the tensors and the data types expected by the functions. My hunch is that `K.ones_like(n_classes)`  needs to be converted to float

Comment: Thank you .... I added some details below the original question under EDIT.

Comment: Hmm, so the TypeError became an InvalidArgumentError? Anyway, the InvalidArgumentError is saying that one of the inputs to `f_score` should be uint8 but is passed as float, you can start from there. Your `gt` should be defined in `train_gen`, while `pr` is the output of your network

Comment: Yes ... thank you. I found that the mask should be float. its working fine now.